# Python Subprocess cannot read all outputs in shell

Tags: python, shell, ide, subprocess, popen

I implemented a python program using subprocess.Popen to execute commands from server to Ubuntu client. The subprocess must read all outputs line by line. **My program operates perfectly  in Eclipse environment**. All outputs print as I expected. 
But when I run the program under Python interactive shell (in both Windows and Linux), subprocess.Popen didnot read all command outputs. The outputs only show little and then Python crashes without any error. Here is my program codes:

```
def execute(self, IP_Instance, command):

    keypairs_directory = Config.keypairs_directory

    cmd = 'ssh ubuntu@%s'%IP_Instance+' -i %s'%keypairs_directory+' %s'%command

    cmd_run = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    for line in cmd_run.stdout:
        print line         
    cmd_run.wait()
```

For example, when I send a command:

```
a.execute('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'ls -l')
```

I have output

```
total 0
```

It is OK. But when I send:

```
a.execute('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'sudo apt-get update')
```

The program only runs to

```
Fetched 8,364 kB in 6s (1,205 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

and then Python backs to

```
>>>
```

I had tried communicate()[0], poll() but they did not bring effectiveness. I use Python 2.7 for all machines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does returning to the interactive prompt map to "crashes without any error"? What do you get for the return code if you instead `return cmd_run.wait()`?

Answer (score 2):

The `apt-get update` command returns data also in standard error, so you need to catch also `stderr` data:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

and then you have to use both `Popen.stdout` and `Popen.stderr`.

Comment: Thank for your fast answer. I have just tried this but unfortunately the result is still the same.

Comment: `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` will redirect `stderr`.

Comment: I get the same outputs. Besides, I try other commands that print a long output and the program also cannot read to print all. For instance sudo apt-get install -y mc. However, in Eclipse, all operate exactly.